# How do I add a new chapter in a book in Pages with the same formatting and (when applicable) icon?

Tags: pages, formatting

I am a fan of the styles of book that they have available to use and edit in this program. I am frustrated when I start a new chapter that I have to copy/paste the title of the last chapter to steal the formatting and then edit it to what I want it to say. Surely there is a way to start a new chapter without this. The template I am using now has an icon as well and makes it extra sloppy. Thank you in advance for any advice.